# Change the size of the text and shape using vertical and horizontal scroll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, scroll, scrollbar

I'm using Visual basic 2012 Ultimate. I want to change the Font size of the text using vertical and horizontal scroll. I tried but the size of the shape changes but not the Text.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub HScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.Scroll
    RectangleShape1.Width = HScrollBar1.Value
    HScrollBar1.Value = TextBox1.Text.

End Sub

Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
    RectangleShape1.Height = VScrollBar1.Value
    VScrollBar1.Value = TextBox1.Text.Size()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing this two lines of your code :

```
HScrollBar1.Value = TextBox1.Text.
...
VScrollBar1.Value = TextBox1.Text.Size()
```

to something like this :

```
TextBox1.FontSize = HScrollBar1.Value 
...
TextBox1.FontSize = VScrollBar1.Value
```

Haven't tested that, but I think you will see that changes in scrollbars make changes in text's Font Size now, after this code modification. However, I'm not sure what you are precisely after. In case of Rectangle, it has width and height so you can associate width with horizontall scrollbar and height with vertical scrollbar. But in case of Font Size it has no such a width and height.

PS: if you actually want something different, *please elaborate what you are actually after, how do you want the modification in vertical and horizontal srollbar value affect Font Size precisely*?